# Convert track length from Spotify to minutes and seconds

Tags: php, spotify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [seconds to minutes and days to weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088109/seconds-to-minutes-and-days-to-weeks)

I wonder how I can convert this value to minutes and seconds: `292.96`. The value is from [this API from Spotify](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=Michael%20Jackson).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what does the value stand for? Seconds?

Comment: @Pekka: I don't know but I think the value is in seconds, yes :)

Comment: Have you tried [Math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math)?

Comment: or this (a bit harshly downvoted, it's not *that* bad): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-seconds-in-php

Comment: @Crashspeeder: No. I'm very bad at mathematics :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$time = 292.96;
$minutes = floor( $time / 60);
$seconds = $time - ($minutes * 60); // Can add floor() or do mod (%) to round
echo $minutes . ' ' . $seconds; // 4 minutes 52.96 seconds
```

Comment: Many thanks for your solutions! It worked :D I'll mark your post as correct as soon as I can.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the value *is* in seconds, so very simple;

```
int minutes = val / 60;
int seconds = val % 60;
```

Comment: I like people who use the modulus operator for things like that! Therefore vote up.